# J2EE application: package does not exist

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, package

The error 'package PackageName does not exist' is thrown from a new j2EE app created in Netbeans.
The app includes a bean and a web application with just one jsp page.
The bean class is in the package called PackageName.

Should have I created my class in default package instead?
Or how otherwise can I notify jsp page that it should look for bean class in my package?
Is there a need to import the package where the bean is stored or somehow else inform the container of the package name?

When writing jsp:usebean the editor sees PackageName and bean's class inside it though...

After reading this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html it is still not clear what is wrong with my package reference in:

```
<jsp:useBean id="classId" scope="application" class="PackageName.ejbClassName"/>
```

@BalusC:

Some reasoning regarding instantiating bean with jsp:usebean http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=48371

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why in earth are you trying to instantiate an EJB class by `<jsp:useBean>` in first place? Also unrelated to the concrete problem, I'd pay more attention and respect to [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) to avoid mistakes made because of lowercase/uppercase inconsitenties. Based on the conventions, the right capitalization is `packagename.EjbClassName` or maybe `packagename.EJBClassName`.

Comment: Ha-ha! Good question! I did that because tutorial called for that style and I have no idea any other instantiation methods exist. I am just following the linked tutorial. Let me try lowercase the package and see if it fixes anything... Nope, the IDE still can see package/class and then variable classId with property underneadth it, but I get the same run time error.

Comment: As said, the comment was unrelated to the problem. Look, it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As a general advise, you should always be careful with the casing, as Java is Case Sensitive i.e. don't mix PackageName, packagename and packageName.

Comment: That's fine, appreciate it! I am mindful of the case and just keep wondering why even though IDE can see the package/class/property, the runtime cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for

```
<jsp:useBean id="classId" scope="application" class="packagename.ejbClassName"/>
```

to work two conditions need to be met:

1. Bean classes have to be under WEB-INF/classes/packagename (NetBeans does not deploy them there automatically)
2. page must import packagename.ejbClassName

Then everything works.

Comment: The most amazing part was that as soon as I added a servlet to the project, #1 was no longer required.